# Acoustic noise in Phone 6

Tags: iphone, speakers

I recently noticed that the speaker of my iPhone 6 yields an acoustic noise in certain situations. After the speakers are used (playing music, click sound when locking the iPhone, etc) I can hear some noise from the speakers for about 5s. The noise is really faint. Is this normal? Does anyone hear it too?

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, but 'acoustic noise' is a little redundant and non-descriptive. Is it a white noise hiss? Is it musical? Does it have a crackling sound? Does it sound like a voice? Is it a slow (or fast) clicking? What does it sound like _to you_?

Comment: That would be a consequence of not being mother tongue speaker :) I would say it is a white noise hiss. No clicking or crackling sounds. Not musical or voice like.

Comment: To clarify: _any time_ a noise (interface click, music, etc) stops, there is immediately a little white noise afterwards, and it is coming from the speakers built into the iPhone? Is the noise present when you listen over earbuds or headphones?

Comment: Yes, any time! And no, it is not present over earplugs.

Comment: Next thing I'd do is back up the iPhone to iTunes on Mac or PC (make a fresh encrypted backup so all your saved passwords are retained) then erase and restore to reload iOS. If the noise recurs, then a trip to the Apple Store may be your next step. Personally, I turn off all the interface sounds.

Comment: @IconDaemon I just did all the things you've mentioned. I got a brand new iPhone. Guess what, the noise is still there! I was hoping somebody else is experiencing the same issue, or can tell me that it is not an issue at all. Maybe it is just normal to have that few seconds of noise?

Comment: Perhaps you have very sensitive ears! This may sound like an odd question, but how old are you? Also, do other people hear this noise from your iPhone, too? Do you hear this noise on other people's iPhones?

Comment: Well, I am 29. And yes, other people hear it too. And I've never checked other iPhones actually. Only my old one and the one I got in exchange. Both had that noise...